# Print Caesar Shift in C is printing the entered text of HELLO

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am trying to perform a Caesar cipher from text from user using modulo operation with the ascii characters. But, my code simply prints the entered test. For example, when the text entered is HELLO the program returns "HELLO". The goal is for a key of 13 it should print URYYB. Thank you.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int key = atoi(argv[1]);

string plaintext = get_string("Enter plaintext: ");

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
{
    if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
    {
        if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key) % 26) + 65);
        }
        else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key) % 26) + 97);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `atoi` is not a particularlly good function as it does not indicate an error i.e. if the string is not a number

Comment: `string` is that some typedef for `char*` ? probably good to show your get_string function, i suspect you return something that no longer exists, then you get undefined behavior.

Comment: duplicate of [Character Shift returning same as original character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53893954/995714)

Comment: ( 'H' + 13 ) = 72 + 13 = 85, 85 % 26 = 7, 7 + 65 = H

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, I recommend iterating until you find the terminating NUL byte (zero, `'\0'`) of the string instead of using `strlen`. (In this case you are also re-calculating the length of the string on every iteration in theory, which is a bad habit worth getting rid of, even if in this kind of simple program it is insignificant and potentially optimised away by the compiler.)

Comment: you don't have a main function. `int key = atoi(argv[1]);` doesn't work at file level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preliminary analysis

Character code of 'H' is 72.

(72 + 13) % 26 + 65 = 85 % 26 + 65 = 7 + 65 ~ 'H'

Let's see if we subtract 65 first:

(72 - 65 + 13) % 26 + 65 = (7 + 13) % 26 + 65 = 20 % 26 + 65 = 20 + 65 = 85 ~ 'U'

## Solution

```
printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key - 65) % 26) + 65);
```

and

```
printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key - 97) % 26) + 97);
```

respectively.

## Proof

If you have a character code, C, where S <= C < S + 26, then the formula you used is:

((C + key) % 26) + S

however, the actual letter is L and we know that

C = S + L,

so the formula is

((S + L + key) % 26) + S

and, since

(A + B) % C = ((A % C) + (B % C)) % C,

replacing A with (S), B with (L + key) and C with 26, we get:

((S % 26) + ((L + key) % 26)) % 26, we see that the result is distorted by (S % 26), which, in the case of 65 is exactly 13. Since a distortion of 13 + the key of 13 you used in the modulo class of 26 will yield the initial letter!

So, the proposed new formula of

((C + key - S) % 26) + S = (((S + L) + key - S) % 26) + S = ((L + key) % 26) + S

is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `key` to the value of each plaintext character, when it is meant to apply to the corresponding letter's index in the alphabet. For example, in case of the `'H'` in ASCII, your formula is: `(72 + 13) % 26` which gives `7` (which is also the index of H in the alphabet, when starting from zero).

You need to convert the (ASCII) value of the character to its index before applying key, e.g., `((plaintext[i] - 'A' + key) % (1 + 'Z' - 'A')) + 'A'`.

The solution for `'H'` would then become `(72 - 65 + 13) % 26`, which gives `20` (the correct answer, `7 + 13`, the index of U).

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as it is correct, but I had given the same solution earlier :)

Comment: @LajosArpad Well, 1 min difference means we were both typing at the same time, but I also upvoted yours (although I would prefer substituting the magic number `65` with `'A'`).

Comment: I know you were not copying mine, it would have been impossible in this amount of time and even otherwise I would not assume such thing. I was just pointing out a funny fact. As about replacing 65 with 'A' makes sense, however, I used the 65 because the asker used it as well. However, I agree that 'A' is more readable for the human eye.

Comment: @LajosArpad _In theory_ the program could also be run with a non-ASCII-compatible character set, in which case 65 would be incorrect while `'A'` might still work (if the letters of the alphabet were still contiguous and in order). =)

Comment: Good point, however, that would be outside the scope of the specification we can read in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your cipher function just does nothing if the key is 13:

run a bit amended one and see the result :D

```
int main()
{
    int key = 13;

    char  plaintext[] = "HELLO";

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%d, %d\n", (int)plaintext[i], (int)(((plaintext[i] + key) % 26) + 65));
            }
            else 
            {
                if (islower(plaintext[i]))
                {
                    //printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key) % 26) + 97);
                }
                else
                {
                    //printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```